# AsyncTask NameValuePair not sending value

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, asynchronous

I am sending values to a PHP file using AsyncTask in Android Studio.
I make an `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` and then add my values with `nameValuePairs.add` and send them to my PHP file which executes the request to a MySQL database.
It works perfectly fine for the first four values but the next values are not sent and I can't find why since it's exactly the same structure as the first four.
When I try to add the "pa" parameters nothing is added in database.

Here I call my function (parameters contains right values):

```
 DbConnect dlTask = new DbConnect();

 if (tabActifChoisis.length == 3) {

     String pa = tabActifChoisis[0];                
     dlTask.execute(sexe, age, formule, base, pa);
 }
```

Here I add values in my array and send them

```
public class DbConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sexe", param[0].toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", param[1].toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formule", param[2].toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base", param[3].toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", param[4].toString()));

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/AppBdd.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            client.execute(httppost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I get the values in PHP and execute my function which is supposed to add them to my db:

```
<?php
require_once ("rees.php");

$pdo = PdoGsb::getPdoGsb();


$sexe = $_REQUEST['sexe'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];
$form  = $_REQUEST['formule'];
$base = $_REQUEST['base'];
$pa  = $_REQUEST['pa'];

$pdo->setClient($sexe, $age, $form, $base, $pa);
```

and my PDO object:

```
<?php 

class PdoGsb{
    private static $serveur='mysql:host=localhost';
    private static $bdd='dbname=testdepeau';        
    private static $user='root';
    private static $mdp='';
    private static $monPdo;
    private static $monPdoGsb=null;

    private function __construct(){
        PdoGsb::$monPdo = new PDO(PdoGsb::$serveur.';'.PdoGsb::$bdd, PdoGsb::$user, PdoGsb::$mdp); 
        PdoGsb::$monPdo->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        PdoGsb::$monPdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        PdoGsb::$monPdo = null;
    }

    public  static function getPdoGsb(){
        if(PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb==null){
            PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb= new PdoGsb();
        }
        return PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb;  
    }

    public function setClient($sexe, $age, $form, $base, $pa){
        $req="INSERT INTO client (formule, sexe, age, base, pa)
         VALUES
         ('$form', '$sexe', '$age', '$base', '$pa');";
         $res2= PdoGsb::$monPdo->exec($req);
    }

}
?>
```

Other information:

- Android and my PHP file are well connected since I can send the first four values.
- `pa` and all the parameters contains the right values, all String type.
- It works perfectly fine if I replace `$pa  = $_REQUEST['p1'];` by `$pa  = "test";` in PHP so I've got no problems on PHP and database side.
- It still doesn't work if I replace 
  `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", param[4].toString()));`
  by
  `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", "test"));`
- `$_POST`, `$_GET` are not working better.

What do I need to fix?

Comment: I'm not too good at web connections, but shouldn't the request key and BasicNameValuePair have the same key ( one is 'pa' and one is 'p1')

Comment: yes my bad miss edit, the key are 'pa' everywhere sry